# Como colocar autoria usando licença MIT

Tags: licença

Segundo a licença MIT tenho que colocar o direitos do autor e onde? Ou não preciso de colocar?

Licença MIT

> The MIT License (MIT)
>
> Copyright (c) 2014-2015 almasaeed2010
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
>   the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
>   EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
>   MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
>   IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
>   CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
>   TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
>   SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Já ressalto que eu não sou advogado. Se você tem maiores preocupações, consulte um. O risco é seu de confiar em pessoas aleatórias te informando sobre leis e licenças.

Se você está só usando não tem que fazer qualquer coisa. Se está modificando também não tem muito o que fazer.

[MIT](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) é uma licença bem permissiva. Essencialmente ela só proíbe você dizer que o código é seu, você não pode alegar autoria se não foi você que fez. Ninguém sequer precisa saber se você está usando algum software com licença MIT em um produto ou serviço seu. Você pode distribuir seus softwares contendo código MIT sem falar para ninguém. Não tem nenhum requisito. Internamente se você até disser que foi você que escreveu aquele código não vai acontecer nada, você só não pode trocar o nome do autor pelo seu e publicar o código.

**Se for publicar** os fontes de sua própria versão, mesmo que dentro de outro projeto seu, você pode se adicionar como coautor se adicionou algo expressivo na sua versão. Aí você coloca no lugar mais apropriado, no cabeçalho do arquivo, indicando com clareza onde você contribuiu, ou no cabeçalho da função alterada. Só tome o cuidado de deixar claro que você não é o autor original.

MIT é próxima do domínio público, exceto que ela não abre mão da autoria. Mas abre mão de todos os direitos de cópia, uso e distribuição.

Esta licença existe mais para liberar os autores de garantias e responsabilidades e não permitir que você "roube" a autoria e processe outras pessoas alegando que elas estão usando algo que você não tenha direitos. Na prática ela serve só para isto. Ela pode ser melhor que domínio público que dá margem à interpretação da autoria.

MIT é a verdadeira licença de software livre. Não é um livre esquizofrênico onde você tem um monte de obrigação.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).